# Vlang module calls confusion

Tags: module, vlang

```
Basics
| main.v
| beta.v
|
|__ parent
   | mod1.v
   |
   |__ child
      | mod2.v
```

Codes:

***main.v***

```
import parent
import parent.child as pc

fn main(){
  parent.name_parent()
  pc.name_child()
}
```

***mod1.v***

```
module parent

pub fn name_parent(){
  println('Parent!!!')
}
```

***mod2.v***

```
module child

pub fn name_child(){
  println('child!!!')
}
```

***beta.v***

```
pub fn beta_test(){
  println('Beta!!!')
}
```

Need some insight on the module structure:

1. Error when I run main.v to access child directory.

   ```
   *error: unknown function: parent.child.name_child*
   ```
2. How to access beta.v  function from main.v ?

Comment: `v run ./` instead of `v run main.v` would include function from `beta.v`.

Comment: I just tried recreating the folder structure you provided and it's giving the same error. I don't think it's supposed to do that, so it's probably a bug with V itself.

Comment: @AdamOates, they mentioned a similar submodule program in vlang/examples/submodule. It is working fine, try once if possible!! just open your git pull and run, it somehow works!~~

Comment: do you have a `v.mod` file?

Answer (score 1):

As [@Immature trader](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13387730/immature-trader) suggested, the solution is to create a file `v.mod` in the root of your module. For example:

```
Basics
| v.mod    << added
| main.v
| beta.v
...
```

The initial contents of `v.mod`, for example:

```golang
Module {
  name: 'Basics',
  description: 'Test submodules.',
  version: '0.0.1'
  dependencies: []
}
```

Compiling and running works:

```
❯ v .
❯ v run .
Parent!!!
child!!!
```

You need to set the root directory for the resolution of relative file paths within a V module. That's what the file `v.mod` does. Unfortunately, it's not documented in the [chapter about V modules](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/doc/docs.md#modules). There's an [open issue to add this information to the documentation](https://github.com/vlang/v/issues/16570).